# Redshift error Overflow for NUMERIC(8,4)

Tags: amazon-redshift

Why do I get "Overflow for NUMERIC(8,4)" for 10595.148?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, so it follows the [PostgreSQL rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html) for numeric data types.

`NUMERIC(8,4)` indicates a *scale* of 4, so it will try to store your number with 4 decimal digits in the fraction part: `10595.1480`. This number has 9 digits, which is higher than the *precision* of 8. The maximum number you can store in this data type is `9999.9999`.

Comment: I see... so they always try to pad the fraction part to fit the scale. Thank you for the explanation.